# Can't create ad-hoc network

Tags: wireless, network-manager, adhoc

I seem to have trouble creating an ad-hoc network in XUbuntu. I'm using the network manager to create the ad-hoc network. However, I can't then connect to the network using the same machine (as the instructions say I should). On other devices I can't see the network at all.

I'm running the latest XUbuntu and I have the following network card:

```
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: Sony Corporation Device 907b
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
Memory at c3404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at c3400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

I saw [this related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136859/how-to-make-ad-hoc-network-connection) but the problem is that I can't then connect to the network on the same machine.

Comment: You need a wireless card to create ad hoc network. The spec you posted is a ethernet card. The ethernet card doesn't have any transmitter to create a wireless ad hoc network